# Sets Data Type in Cassandra

Tags: node.js, cassandra

```
create table Rooms(
id uuid primary key,
groups set<text>);
```

This is my database schema. I wanted to insert certain values in my set groups. If i do this by using my console window then no error pops up but I am using node.js for my backend work.
Here is my code.

```
var query = 'insert into Rooms(id,groups)values(now(),?)';
var params = [{user1,user2}];
client.execute(query,params,{prepare:true},(err,res)=>{
if(!err){
//
}else{
//
}
});
```

Here user1 and user2 are two variables.
and This is the error

> TypeError: Not a valid list value, expected Array obtained { userId: '3c059df0-e651-11e7-b2be-a58a1c9976cf',
>     user_id: 'dlsfdslfsdlfjdsf' }

Here is my client

```
var client = new Cassandra.Client({
contactPoints:['127.0.0.1'],
keyspace:'roomkey',
encoding:{
set:Set
}
});
```

Comment: you should bind Array and you are passing object hence error.. `var params = ['3c059df0-e651-11e7-b2be-a58a1c9976cf','dhdgas-e651-11e7-b2be-a58a1c9976cf'];`

Comment: That means we cannot store objects in Sets Data type of Cassandra ?

Comment: you can store primitive datatypes.. I am not sure about UDT's but if you need key-value pairs there is map data type